# How to have inherited functions use local variables

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I want to apply the functions from one class to the private variables from another derived class. I was hoping that this way I could avoid redefining the exact same function multiple times.

I've added an example below.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void print1();
    void print2();
private:
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void print3();
private:
    int array[3] = {4, 5, 6};
};

void A::print1() {
    std::cout << this->array[0] << std::endl;
}

void A::print2() {
    std::cout << this->array[1] << std::endl;
}

void B::print3() {
    print1();
    print2();
    std::cout << this->array[2] << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    B b;
    b.print3(); // Output = 1 2 6, I want = 4 5 6
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that perhaps defining the *array* in class *A* and *B* as public, so it would get overwritten, would work, but this did not have any effect.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: As you've noticed, `A::array` and `B::array` are two different variables. If you only want `A::array`, just remove `B::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions, related to design patterns called "Non-virtual interface" or "Template methods".

Without virtual methods: add a member which will point to the private array:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() : array(_array) {}
    void print1();
    void print2();
  protected:
    A(int array[3]) : array(array) {}
    int *array;
  private:
    int _array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

class B: public A {
  public:
    B() : A(_array) {}
    void print3();
  private:
    int _array[3] = {4, 5, 6};
};
```

Or add a virtual method, which will return the pointer:

```
class A {
  public:
    void print1();
    void print2();
  protected:
    virtual int *array() { return _array; };
  private:
    int _array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

class B: public A {
  public:
    void print3();
  protected:
    virtual int *array() { return _array; };
  private:
    int _array[3] = {4, 5, 6};
};
```

In this second solution use `array()` instead of `array` in methods (`std::cout << this->array()[0] << std::endl;` etc.).

Comment: That's a great idea! I don't actually need to access the variables directly. I can just use a function that gets overwritten when the class is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation of `print1` and `print2` must be in the base class, then you need some form of polymorphic access to the array associated with the object instance.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void print1();
    void print2();

private:
    virtual const int* getArray() const { return array; };
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void print3();
private:
    virtual const int* getArray() const { return array; };
    int array[3] = {4, 5, 6};
};

void A::print1() {
    std::cout << this->getArray()[0] << std::endl;
}

void A::print2() {
    std::cout << this->getArray()[1] << std::endl;
}

void B::print3() {
    print1();
    print2();
    std::cout << this->getArray()[2] << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    B b;
    b.print3(); // Outputs 4 5 6
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance does not work like this, you are close to get it, but your design needs a small change. What you need to do is to change your `print1` and `print2` functions, to receive the argument you want to print:

```
class A {
public:
    void print1(int num);
    ...
private:
    int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};

void A::print1(int num) {
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

Then you call the `print1` and `print2` functions with the `int` you are interested:

```
void B::print3() {
    print1(array[0]);
    print2(array[1]);
    std::cout << this->array[2] << std::endl;
}
```

This will call those functions in your class `B` with the values stored in the "override" `array`, and you will have the output you are looking for:

```
int main() {
    B b;
    b.print3(); // Output = 4 5 6
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you're going to do it that way, then `print1` and `print2` should be static

Comment: Why do you think should be static?